# Using a case statement to show the count of two types of values in a column

Tags: sql

```
SELECT
    qt.name,
    CASE
        WHEN qr.isfinished = 0 THEN COUNT(qr.resultid) 
    END AS 'Attempted',
    CASE
        WHEN qr.isfinished = 1 THEN COUNT(qr.resultid) 
    END AS 'Completed'
```

Need it to show attempted and completed values on the same row

```
 Name        attempted  Completed
 --------------------------------
 Algebra I   114        NULL
 Algebra II   47        NULL
 ASVAB        55        NULL
 Algebra I   NULL       69
 Algebra II  NULL       55
 ASVAB       NULL       84
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If `isfinished` is `bit`, you can't aggregate on it.
And the CASE goes inside the COUNT

```
SELECT qt.name,
 count(Case when qr.isfinished = 0 THEN 1 END) as 'Attempted',
 count(Case when qr.isfinished = 1 THEN 1 END) as 'Completed'
FROM
 ...
GROUP BY
 qt.name
```

Comment: This ran, but its showing 0, instead of null and still repeating the rows =/
and isfinished is bit, thanks for the pointer!

Comment: No you didn't run this code. It's impossible to get NULL with COUNT (it's zero or more than zero) and to duplicate rows with a single GROUP BY

Comment: i edited my original post to show the result and query

Comment: My mistake, i have an extra group by column in there. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you could do this, for example you could do this with joins, or you can use group by -- like so:

```
SELECT
    qt.name,
    SUM(CASE qr.isfinsihed WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS 'Attempted',
    SUM(CASE qr.isfinished WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS 'Completed'
FROM -- what ever your from clause is, it goes here --
GROUP BY
    qt.name
```

In order to have them on the same row, you will need to group by what they have in common. From what you have given in the question, I am assuming that is the qt.name.

Next, you can use the SUM aggregate to get each field count. All of the records that meet the criteria for each item count towards the sum, the others don't. You can also use count with 1's and Null's, I prefer using Sum because it can allow for weighted totals if I need them.

Comment: SO, would you like to say something ?